# Strange shutdown behavior

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am having multiple problems with the following, apparently almost-trivial, code.

`main.py`

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys
import time

test_ui = True

if test_ui:
    class Module:
        def __init__(self, tag):
            self.tag = tag
            self.mac = '12:34:56:78:90:AB'
else:
    from ftdi import Module


class Handler(QRunnable):
    class Signals(QObject):
        set_txt = pyqtSignal(str)
        set_prg = pyqtSignal(int)

    def set_txt(self, txt):
        self.txt.setText(txt)

    def set_prg(self, val):
        self.pro.setValue(val)

    def __init__(self, txt, pro, chn):
        super().__init__()
        self.txt = txt
        self.pro = pro
        self.chn = chn
        self.signals = self.Signals()
        self.cnt = 0
        self.cmd = ''
        self.signals.set_txt.connect(lambda x: self.txt.setText(x))
        self.signals.set_prg.connect(lambda x: self.pro.setValue(x))
        self.sema = QSemaphore()

    def next(self):
        self.cmd = 'next'
        self.sema.release(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.cmd = 'stop'
        self.sema.release(1)

    def redo(self):
        self.cmd = 'redo'
        self.sema.release(1)

    def is_idle(self):
        return not self.cmd

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.signals.set_txt.emit('idle.')
        while True:
            self.sema.acquire()
            if self.cmd == 'next':
                self.cnt = 0
                self.signals.set_txt.emit('running...')
                while self.cnt < 100:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    self.cnt += 1
                    self.signals.set_prg.emit(self.cnt)
                self.signals.set_txt.emit('done.')
            elif self.cmd == 'redo':
                break
            elif self.cmd == 'stop':
                break
            self.cmd = ''


class MAC(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.user_data = None

    def set_user_data(self, data):
        self.user_data = data

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        if self.user_data:
            h = self.user_data['handler']
            if h and h.is_idle():
                text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'MAC', 'Edit MAC address', text=self.user_data['mac'])
                if ok:
                    # TODO: check format
                    self.user_data['mac'] = str(text)
                    pb = self.user_data['progress']
                    pb.setFormat(self.user_data['mac'])


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("main.ui", self)

        # self.bquit = self.findChild(QPushButton, 'bquit')
        self.bquit.pressed.connect(self.quit_)
        # self.bnext = self.findChild(QPushButton, 'bnext')
        self.bnext.pressed.connect(self.do_next)

        # find the widgets in the xml file
        self.cells = {}

        for i in '12':
            for j in 'abcd':
                c = {
                    'group': self.findChild(QGroupBox, f'g{i}{j}'),
                    'label': self.findChild(QLineEdit, f'l{i}{j}'),
                    'progress': self.findChild(QProgressBar, f'p{i}{j}'),
                }
                try:
                    m = Module(f'{i}{j}')
                except IndexError:
                    c['group'].setEnabled(False)
                else:
                    c['mac'] = m.mac
                    c['module'] = m
                self.cells[f'{i}{j}'] = c

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        # print(f'max_thread_count: {self.threadpool.maxThreadCount()}')
        self.threadpool.setMaxThreadCount(8)
        # print(f'max_thread_count: {self.threadpool.maxThreadCount()}')

        for v in self.cells.values():
            la = v['label']
            pb = v['progress']
            if v['group'].isEnabled():
                la.setText('')
                la.setReadOnly(True)
                pb.setValue(0)
                pb.setTextVisible(True)
                pb.setFormat(v['mac'])
                pb.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                pb.installEventFilter(self.SetMac(v))
                v['handler'] = Handler(la, pb, v['module'])
                self.threadpool.start(v['handler'])
                pb.set_user_data(v)
            else:
                la.setText('DISCONNESSO')
                la.setReadOnly(True)
                pb.setMaximum(0)
                pb.setMinimum(0)

        self.show()

    class SetMac(QObject):
        def __init__(self, cell):
            super().__init__()
            self.cell = cell

        def eventFilter(self, o: 'QObject', e: 'QEvent') -> bool:
            if e.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
                print('*** DoubleClick ***')
                return True
            return super().eventFilter(o, e)
                
    @pyqtSlot()
    def quit_(self):
        QCoreApplication.quit()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def do_next(self):
        for v in self.cells.values():
            h = v.get('handler')
            if h:
                if h.cmd:
                    print('already running')
                else:
                    h.next()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def shutdown(self):
        for v in self.cells.values():
            h = v.get('handler')
            if h:
                h.stop()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.aboutToQuit.connect(window.shutdown)
app.exec_()
print('at end')
```

`main.ui`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>345</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_9">
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="f1">
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>52</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>1</string>
         </property>
         <property name="scaledContents">
          <bool>false</bool>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>10</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="g1a">
            <property name="title">
             <string>A</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
             <item>
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l1a"/>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="MAC" name="p1a">
               <property name="value">
                <number>24</number>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="g1b">
            <property name="title">
             <string>B</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
             <item>
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l1b"/>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="MAC" name="p1b">
               <property name="value">
                <number>24</number>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="g1c">
            <property name="title">
             <string>C</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
             <item>
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l1c"/>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="MAC" name="p1c">
               <property name="value">
                <number>24</number>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="g1d">
            <property name="title">
             <string>D</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
             <item>
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l1d"/>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="MAC" name="p1d">
               <property name="value">
                <number>24</number>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="f2">
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>52</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>2</string>
         </property>
         <property name="scaledContents">
          <bool>false</bool>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_4">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>10</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="g2a">
            <property name="title">
             <string>A</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_6">
             <item>
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l2a"/>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="MAC" name="p2a">
               <property name="value">
                <number>24</number>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="g2b">
            <property name="title">
             <string>B</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
             <item>
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l2b"/>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="MAC" name="p2b">
               <property name="value">
                <number>24</number>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="g2c">
            <property name="title">
             <string>C</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_7">
             <item>
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l2c"/>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="MAC" name="p2c">
               <property name="value">
                <number>24</number>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QGroupBox" name="g2d">
            <property name="title">
             <string>D</string>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_8">
             <item>
              <widget class="QLineEdit" name="l2d"/>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="MAC" name="p2d">
               <property name="value">
                <number>24</number>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5">
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="bquit">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Esci</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="bnext">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
           <horstretch>10</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Avanti il prossimo</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="bredo">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Recupera</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MAC</class>
   <extends>QProgressBar</extends>
   <header>main</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Beside other small quirks I get a very strange shutdown behavior:
if I either hit the [Esci] button or I click on the close window button in main window decoration a *second*, identical window is displayed after worker threads are shut down.
A second click closes windows but does *not* exit application (it won't even respond to control-C) and I need to kill it from outside.

It seems threads are not really terminated.

What am I doing so wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a promoted widget, that is imported from the same file.

When loading an ui that uses a promoted widget, uic actually *imports* the file that contains it, and as with any import statement, everything in the main indentation level of the imported file is actually executed.

The result is that your program is actually run twice.

That's another reason for which it is *very* important to use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` check.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UI()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(window.shutdown)
    app.exec_()
    print('at end')
```